# python convert microsoft office docs to plain text on linux

Tags: python, linux, ms-office

Any recomendations on a method to convert .doc, .ppt, and .xls to plain text on linux using python? Really any method of conversion would be useful. I have already looked at using Open Office but, I would like a solution that does not require having to install Open Office.

Comment: I went with a command line solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd go for the command line-solution (and then use the [Python subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to run the tools from Python).

Convertors for msword (**catdoc**), excel (**xls2csv**) and ppt (**catppt**) can be found (in source form) here: http://vitus.wagner.pp.ru/software/catdoc/.

Can't really comment on the usefullness of catppt but catdoc and xls2csv work great!

But be sure to first search your distributions repositories... On ubuntu for example catdoc is just one fast apt-get away.

Comment: +1 for not using open office formats, just like the OP wanted.

Answer (score 9):

You can access [OpenOffice via Python API](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python).

Try using this as a base: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Odt2txt.py

Answer (score 5):

The usual tool for converting Microsoft Office documents to HTML or other formats was mswordview, which has since been renamed to [vwWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/).

If you're looking for a command-line tool, they actually recommend using AbiWord to perform the conversion:

```
AbiWord --to=txt
```

If you're looking for a library, start on the [wvWare overview page](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/wvWare.html). They also maintain [a list of libraries and tools which read MS Office documents](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/wvInfo.html).

Answer (score 2):

At the command line, [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) or [wv](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/) work very nicely for .doc files. (Not a Python solution, but they're easy to install and fast.)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. Below is my simple script to convert all doc files in dir 'docs/' to dir 'txts/' using catdoc. Hope it will help someone:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob, re, os
f = glob.glob('docs/*.doc') + glob.glob('docs/*.DOC')

outDir = 'txts'
if not os.path.exists(outDir):
    os.makedirs(outDir)
for i in f:
    os.system("catdoc -w '%s' > '%s'" %
              (i, outDir + '/' + re.sub(r'.*/([^.]+)\.doc', r'\1.txt', i,
                                   flags=re.IGNORECASE)))
```

Comment: Haha...+1 for using python...to use bash. Good job sticking with the OP's requests...sort of. `:D`

Comment: @Droogans: he, he, these multi-language quick scripts are really ironic. I've started doing in bash, the rules to change the output file name became weird, then I just put it inside a python script. Easier than using subprocess module, pipes etc.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with Excel Spreadsheets [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) is good.  But it won't help with `.doc` and `.ppt` files.

(You may have also heard of PyExcelerator.  xlwt is a fork of this and better maintained so I think you'd be better of with xlwt.)

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success at using XSLT to process the XML-based office files into something usable in the past. It's not necessarily a python-based solution, but it does get the job done.