# How to read pdf, ppt, xl, doc files content into a string in php/python

Tags: php, python, file

Pls suggest me any inbuilt command or package?

Answer (score 2):

well, it shouldn't be too hard to find something from the net. Here's one for Python called [pyPDF](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/). Check [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/) also for such modules. As for reading doc,ppt,xls files, one way is to use [COM](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html).

Answer (score 1):

The content as in "binary" or the actual text?

To read the file as "binary" in php:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

In python:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Actually reading the contents of the file is a lot more difficult and requires additonall libraries. For instance have a look at this question on SO (Python):
[python convert microsoft office docs to plain text on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685533/python-convert-microsoft-office-docs-to-plain-text-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = fopen('myfile.png', 'rb'); // read in binary mode.

if ($data) {
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  fpassthru($data);
}
```

You should change `content-type` accordingly.