# Edit RTF file using Python

Tags: python, rtf, pyparsing

Maybe this is a dumb question, but I don't get it so appologize :)

I have an RTF document, and I want to change it. E.g. there is a table, I want to duplicate a row and change the text in the second row in my code in an object-oriented way.

I think pyparsing should be the way to go, but I'm fiddling around for hours and don't get it. I'm providing no example code because it's all nonsense I think :/

Am I on the right path or is there a better approach?

Anyone did something like that before?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your questions.

Comment: Could you at least post a snippet of what you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFs are text documents with special "symbols" to create the formatting. (see - http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod#RTF_Document_Structure It seems that perl has a good RTF library though), so yes, PyParsing is a good way to go. You have to learn the structure and then parse (there are perl code examples in the page i mentioned. If you are lucky you can translate them in python with some effort)

There is a basic RTF module available for python. Check - http://pyrtf.sourceforge.net/

Hope that helps you a little.

Comment: two other resources : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337446/is-there-a-python-module-for-converting-rtf-to-plain-text
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278850/doc-rtf-and-txt-reader-in-python

Comment: yea I saw the pyRtf and I think it doesn't fit.

'bout pyparsing ... do you know some easy understandable examples with a bit more than 'hello, world!'?

For RTF I found the official Microsoft description - it's fairly easy but a bit vague. E.g. table rows could end with "\row" or with "\row \pard" which is a bit confusing, but I would handle that. What I really don't get is the concept of pyparsing.

Comment: Think I will order this: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/9780596514235

Comment: Have seen you this page? it has a lot of example for pyparsing : http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples Also, the book you have mentioned is the official book for pyparsing. So, i guess it will be a good reading

Comment: I'm marking the above as solution, as it gives the right hints. However, for me personally I found a better solution using odf-files and zipfile. Thank you all!