# Compare two RTF files using Python

Tags: python, rtf, file-comparison

I have two folders with RTF files, the filenames are same in both folders
RTF files consists of Header and Footer in every page
I have to ignore the Header and Footer part in every page and compare the content of body part
I did something like this so far, Im not sure whether this is the right way but it works(reads and compare the exact content)

```
txt_1 = 'D:\\files\\1'
txt_2 = 'D:\\files\\2'

fol_1 = []
fol_2 = []
for fname in os.listdir(path=txt_1):
    fol_1.append(fname)
for fname in os.listdir(path=txt_2):
    fol_2.append(fname)

for i in fol_1:
    for j in fol_2:
        if i == j:
            file_1 = open(txt_1 + '\\' + i).read()
            file_2 = open(txt_2 + '\\' + j).read()
            if file_1 == file_2:
                print('Matches')
            else:
                print('Files didnt match: ' + i)
```

Is there any way to ignore the Header and Footer part in every page
Or is there any way to ignore a String/Line in the footer/header part
Is there any python modules i should look for,
Please give me some suggestions, thank you!

Comment: How did you ignored header and footer?

Comment: @AliTou No, i don't know how to ignore the header and footer. I'm wondering if there is any way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we can't directly read and compare RTF files based on your code.
You have to use additional RTF libraries in your code to read and manipulate your logic.

See if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899328/edit-rtf-file-using-python) is helpful for you.