# python unicode- when i want to read content in file

Tags: python, unicode

I want to read Chinese file through python code. But i got a messy output.

Following is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open('1.doc', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    print text
```

Output:

```
\x01\x00\x00\xfe\xff\xff\xffy\x01\x00\x00z\x01\x00\x00{\x01\x00\x00|\x01\x00\x00}\x01\x00\x00~\x01\x00\x00\x7f\x01\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x81\x01\x00\x00\x82\x01\
```

I know that it must have some encode or decode problems in there. But i don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: What were you expecting to get?

Comment: @一二三 the file's content is Chinese. I want it to display Chinese.

Comment: If you're opening a MS Word document, you're going to have to either convert it first manually, or if you're on Windows use the COM interface as described http://stackoverflow.com/a/32049165/69893 there.

Comment: @ChristianWitts I have tried to convert it to txt type. And the output changed to something like this  \\u21516 \\u30340 \\u27835 \\u23398 \\u24577 \\u24230 \\u65292 \\u35848 \\u35848 \\u20320 \\u33719 \\u24471 \\u30340 \\u21551 \\u31034 \\u12290 \\\n'

Comment: related: [extracting text from MS word files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/125222/4279)

Comment: @曾锐鸿: update your question or ask a new one: include the code that produces the new output and the output itself (exactly as you see it).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything to do with Chinese. This is a Word doc, which is a binary file format. You can't just read it via `readlines`: you'll need to convert it from that binary file format. A library like [docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx) will help.

Comment: The `docx` library only works with Word 2007+ documents in the .docx format, and not for older documents using the .doc format.

Comment: @曾锐鸿 I specifically said you *cannot* read it like that, so why did you say that?

Answer (score 0):

to display Unicode you system chars you sistem must my configured. Check what is configuration of you environment with sys.getdefaultencoding(), if is not outputting utf-8 you will not get chinese displayed. if you on Window read with encoding='cp1252', but first check the environment.

Comment: @曾锐鸿 so google how co configure you particular editor and console, also